# Form validation syntax - calling form.save() versus foo.save()

Tags: django, django-forms

I am processing a ModelForm, and both of these seem to return identical results:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FooForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        bar = form.save(commit = False)
        bar.user = request.user
        form.save()


if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FooForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        bar = form.save(commit = False)
        bar.user = request.user         
        bar.save()               # calling save on bar instead of on the form
```

In terms of how these save data and relations between data, is there any difference in these two? The second approach doesn't seem to work when I need to use bar.save_m2m(), which makes me think that the first approach is the right way to go. However, the logic of the second approach makes more sense to me. Can anyone clarify for me which one of these is more correct and why? I am worried that I am unintentionally processing data incorrectly and setting my app up for problems down the line.

Comment: The frst example would _not_ save the user field. Since you are not calling save on the `bar` but the form itself.

Comment: And it wouldn't be `bar.save_m2m()`, it would be `form.save_m2m()`, even with the second example.

Comment: I wouldn't use the first one because form.save() will create a copy of bar and bar.user will be whatever the FooForm put on it when being constructed with request.POST.

Comment: @karthikr @DanielRoseman That's the source of my confusion - I thought that in ex1 the user field wouldn't be saved, but in practice it appears to work. If I create a user model then use the form processing from ex1 to save the attached `profile` I can then access `profile.user`, `profile.user.id` etc. If ex1 did NOT work, I would expect that creating a `profile` with the processing from ex1 would yield errors when trying to access `profile.user` and the like. Am I off base?

Comment: That it works now doesn't mean that it will work in the future, just because you can not be sure that FooForm will use the same instance to save information than the one it returned when you called form.save(commit=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django's website, probably this will clear up what you should do:

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> f = AuthorForm(request.POST)

# Create, but don't save the new author instance.
>>> new_author = f.save(commit=False)

# Modify the author in some way.
>>> new_author.some_field = 'some_value'

# Save the new instance.
>>> new_author.save()

# Now, save the many-to-many data for the form.
>>> f.save_m2m()
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/

This is extracted from the source code of Django 1.6.2:

```
if commit:
    # If we are committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
    instance.save()
    save_m2m()
else:
    # We're not committing. Add a method to the form to allow deferred
    # saving of m2m data.
    form.save_m2m = save_m2m
return instance
```

This is the reason why if after Ex1:form.save() you call bar.save_m2m() everything will be fine, you will be executing a normal save() step by step. The Base class is returning its instance each time so if you call save() it will save the same instance you are pointing to from outside and that you just modified (Warning: are you using it as a global variable?)...and anyway you can not be sure for how long this method will work as you expect since nowhere in the documentation says the instance returned when calling form.save(commit=False) is the same instance used when you call form.save() few lines below.

As far as I know you wanted to know which way is better to avoid future problems...my recommendation is: go with the second one!.

Comment: I understand _that_ it works, but I don't really understand _how_. See my comment on the original question: I thought that in ex1 the user field wouldn't be saved, but in practice it appears to work. If I create a user model then use the form processing from ex1 to save the attached profile I can then access profile.user, profile.user.id etc. If ex1 did NOT work, I would expect that creating a profile with the processing from ex1 would yield errors when trying to access profile.user and the like. Am I off base?

Comment: I should add that this actually does answer the question I had regarding which way is the right way to do it, and I appreciate that! Thank you! I still do not understand why example 1 seems to successfully save the user relation though, which means I don't fully understand how the save works. It's academic, but I'm grateful for any additional light that can be shed.

Comment: I just read your edit, brilliant!! I understand much more completely now. Thank you for taking the time to add that extra information!